# How can I rename a sortable nested element based on target parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

If I have a nested list like:

```
root:
- A
    - A1
    - A2
        - A2.1
            - A2.1.1
- B
    - B1
    - B2
- C
```

If I drag an element into another list I want to keep the naming the same as the top element. For example, if I drag something under A1 into C, A1 should be renamed to C because the new parent's name is C. If I drag an element into A2.1.1, it should become A2.1.1.1. Like so:

```
root:
- A
    - A2
        - A2.1
            - A2.1.1
                - A.2.1.1.1
- B
    - B1
    - B2
- C
    - C1
```

Here is a sample JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqttf/37/

I know that in the beforeMove and afterMove function callbacks it provides with you an arg parameter and within that you can get the targetParent. However, targetParent only gives me the array of childrens within that target, there is no way to get the name or the object of the parent itself.

Comment: In your example, after you removed `A1`, should the existing `A2` become `A1`.?

Comment: I think I'll have to consider both scenarios i.e. yes and no to your question, since I don't know yet.

Comment: It makes a big difference. If you change it to `A1`, it means that every "name" is simply based the item's position in the structure.

Comment: I think we will most likely have to change it to A1. The same problem remains though, there is no way to get the target element, only the target observable array and it's children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout provides everything you need to react to changes in the structure and rename items. I've provided an example that uses a simpler naming structure, which you can modify to work the way you want.

```
ko.computed(function () {
  var myName = this.name(), children = this.children();
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(children, function (child, index) {
    child.name(myName + '.' + (index+1));
  });
}, this);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqttf/47/

Comment: In the end I used a subscriber very similar to this method.